# Serving dynamically generated files from GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, api, svg, github-pages

I'm a few months into web development so I apologize if I misunderstood anything.

## What I did

I created a [`react-random-shapes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-random-shapes) package that would draw out random shapes as a React component. You can see an example [here on my site](https://artt.github.io/) or in the [project page](https://artt.github.io/react-random-shapes/). Each time you refresh the page you'd get a new image. (Note: these pages use React.)

## What I want to do next

The result I'm aiming for is to create an API (GET-only) on GitHub Pages that would return the dynamically generated svg file (so you can do something like

```
<img src="https://github.com/artt/react-random-shapes/blob?size=300&fill=red">
```

which would return a random blob for anyone who's interested in using. Alternatively, this API could return the svg path so the user could do whatever they want with it (e.g. animation).

## The problem I have

Right now I know how to output an html page with the svg file, but not quite sure how to return just the svg (or json, etc.) part of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to do the same thing. I think your best bet would be to use a webserver on another platform like Heroku or, another good option, Replit.